# Weaviate cloud exceptions error: WeaviateStartUpError

Tags: weaviate

I’ve created a cluster in WCS. Upon trying to connect from my Python code, I face the challenge below.

```
weaviate.exceptions.WeaviateStartUpError: Weaviate did not start up in 10 seconds. Either the Weaviate URL
```

Did Weaviate not start up in the interval given in ‘startup_period’ or did I do something else wrong?

Could I get some help on this?

Comment: Ho Dinesh – welcome to Stackoverflow! It's best to ask this question on the [Weaviate forum](https://forum.weaviate.io) where the team can help (because it's not a software question persé)